# Require three-line widows but allow two-line orphans

Tags: widows-orphans

I know with `\usepackage[defaultlines=2,all]{nowidow}` I can easily avoid all widows/orphans for a given number of lines.

But what if I want to have different minimum numbers of lines for widows and orphans?  The 16th edition of the Chicago Manual of Style now allows for single-line orphans at the end of a page, but not for widows. Or, what if I want to have a two-line minimum for orphans, but a three-line minimum for widows?

The `all` option of the package seems to be boolean, so no way to define `onlywidows` or `onlyorphans`, or is there? Otherwise, to get the Chicago specs, one could only let it control widows and leave orphans alone.  But is there a way to set the minimum required lines for orphans and widows independently of each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source the package options are only a convenient syntax for simple cases. You can use the command forms such as  `\nowidow[5]` and `\noclub[3]` the default value for the optional arguments in both cases is the value you specified in `defaultlines=` option.

Comment: I should have read the manual more carefully :/  —  The commands you mention are for use at the end of a paragraph though.  What I was looking for were the `\setnowidow[5]` and `\setnoclub[3]` commands but I finally found them.